# ListViewItem with CheckBox IsChecked Binding to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, templatebinding

I have a ListView with a DataTemplate for displaying for each ListViewItem a Checkbox.

[image]

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TableNames}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The ItemsSource ("TableNames") is deklared in the ViewModel like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _TableNames = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public ObservableCollection<Item> TableNames
{
    get { return _TableNames; }
    set
    {
        _TableNames = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TableNames");
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

How can I bind the IsChecked from the Checkbox to the Item.IsSelected property?

My code doesn't work.

Comment: Get rid of "RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
<DataTemplate>    
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. Also thanks to dkozl, your answer explains the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `RelativeSource`

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
```

Since `DataContext` of `ListViewItem` will be set to instance of `Item` all you need to specify is path to `IsSelected`