# ListView selected item access in viewmodel

Tags: wpf, listview, selecteditem

I'm following MVVM pattern. I have a listview control which has multiple checkboxes. my viewmodel has collection of Student which is bounded to listview control.

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> students{ get; private set; }
private ObservableCollection<Student> _displays { get; set; }
```

viewmodel doesn't know anything about the view so it doesn't access to the listview control

I tried by defining the Student class by below

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string class { get; set; }
}
```

In viewmodel, i want to perform some action when user select/unselect the checkbox.
how can I get which items are checked or not, how can i get selected item state in viewmodel?
I'm following mvvm pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359550/listviewitem-with-checkbox-ischecked-binding-to-viewmodel .

Comment: @fmunkert, if you actually read this question, you'll see that the question author said *In viewmodel, i want to perform some action when user select/unselect the checkbox*... you linked question is *not* the same as this.

Comment: @Sheridan: agreed, it is not a 100% duplicate. The linked question does not answer the "perform some action" part, but it answers the "how can I get which items are checked or not" part.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, we generally use data binding. This means that ideally, you would have data bound a property of your `Student` class to a `Checkbox` in the UI:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsSomething { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here
    ...
}
```

...

```
<Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding IsSomething}" />
```

If you do this, then you can find out which `Checkbox`es were checked simply by looking at the relevant `Student` object from your view model:

```
bool isSomething = CurrentStudent.IsSomething;
```

If you want to react to the changing value, then you just have to monitor the property for changes:

```
public bool IsSomething
{
    get { return isSomething; }
    set
    {
        if (value != isSomething) 
        {
            isSomething= value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSomething");
            if (isSomething) CheckedBoxWasChecked();
            else CheckedBoxWasUnChecked();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check multiple items at a time?

If not, you can simple add a SelectedItem property to your view model and bind the SelectedItem property of the listView to the SelectedItem property of the view model.

If you need to be able to check more than one item at a time, you can add a boolean IsSelected property to the Student class. Then in your data template for the list view, bind the IsChecked property of the checkbox to the IsSelected property of the Student.

Please make sure your view model and student class implement INotifyPropertyChanged, etc.

Comment: student is model and i don't want to add IsSelected property in model which is something related to view/viewmodel, want to achieve same through another way using mvvm pattern.